# Make one HTML file get run through the PHP processor

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a file webpage.htm which has 3 or so lines of php in it. I also have other pages with the .htm extension, but I only want webpage.htm to be run through the PHP preprocessor. Is it possible to do that with Apache directives in a .htaccess file?

Comment: Although @Garry answer looks like the best option, yes, it is possible to redirect .htm(l) files to .php files. in .htaccess. They have to exist though and html files should have precedence over .php files. Not necessarily they do, depends on the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can do it by modifying .htaccess file

```
<Files yourpage.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

or for all html/htm pages:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Here is a helpful article 
http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I added AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm to my httpd.conf and it still does not run php script in .htm files.

Comment: @Ulflander I can't restart Apache. We are paying for web hosting and it is on that server, and no, I do not have root access. However, I can edit httpd.conf. PS I have added a line of gibberish to a .htaccess file and promptly reloaded the webpage, and it *did* give an error.

Comment: Good to know, because your web host provider may block this kind of rules for security issues - maybe something to check with them.

Comment: So here the issue comes of security.Nothing wrong with procedure

Comment: @Garry I accepted your answer because AFAIK it **is** the right answer. It is just a thing with the hosting company. I may try calling tech support about it... :(

Comment: I thought may be you are using local server.Because this setting reflect to server setting so hopefully hosting company can help you about this.Good luck